# Why do I need to add a "shim" for AngularJS when using Require.js?

Tags: requirejs

I have seen several examples that use this:

main.js

```
/*global require*/
'use strict';

require.config({
    paths: {
        angular: './angular',
        app: './Content/app',
        ngAnimate: './Scripts/angular-animate',
        uiRouter: './Scripts/angular-ui-router'
    },
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    }
});

require(['angular', 'app'], function (angular) {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

Can someone explain to me why the shim is needed? My application uses other modules such as angular-ui router, jQuery etc. Do I need to do something similar and add a shim for these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rule is pretty simple: if a library/script/package/plugin is AMD-aware, then you don't need a shim. (Actually, you **must not** use a shim for it.) If it is not AMD-aware, then you need a shim.

A library/etc is AMD-aware if it detects that an AMD loader is present and calls `define` to make itself known to the loader.

jQuery from about 1.8 onwards has not needed a shim because it calls `define`. Angular, on the other hand, does not call `define`.

To know whether a specific piece of code needs a shim, you can read its documentation or if the documentation is not clear on this, then you can check the source code for a call to `define`. For instance [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/#jquery-1-x) 1.11.0 has this code:

```
// Register as a named AMD module, since jQuery can be concatenated with other
// files that may use define, but not via a proper concatenation script that
// understands anonymous AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust
// way to register. Lowercase jquery is used because AMD module names are
// derived from file names, and jQuery is normally delivered in a lowercase
// file name. Do this after creating the global so that if an AMD module wants
// to call noConflict to hide this version of jQuery, it will work.
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function() {
        return jQuery;
    });
}
```

How it looks like will vary from one case to the other but the basic think you want to look for is the check that `define` exists, is a function, has the `amd` property set and the call to `define`.

(Note that jQuery is a special case where they decided to hard code the name of the module in the `define` call (first parameter: `jquery`). Generally the name of the module won't be present in the `define` call but will be left for RequireJS to infer on the basis of the file name.)